# Inconsistent Behavior of WebCodecs' copyTo() Method Across Different Browsers and Systems

Tags: javascript, webcodecs

I'm currently facing an intriguing issue with the WebCodecs API, specifically the copyTo() method. While implementing a feature using this method, I've encountered an 'undefined' error. Curiously, this error does not occur consistently across all platforms. On some devices, the code executes perfectly, but on others, it fails with this error.
I would appreciate any insights or experiences you might have regarding this issue.

```
const decoder = new VideoDecoder({
    output(frame) {
        // console.log('frame', frame);
        videoFrames.push(frame);
        ctx.drawImage(frame, 0, 0);
        checkFrameReady();
        frame.close();
    },
    error(e) {
        console.error(e);
    },
});
function checkFrameReady() {
    if (videoFrames.length) {
        const vf = videoFrames[0];
        if (vf && !videoBuffer) {
            videoBuffer = new Uint8Array(vf.allocationSize());
            createVideoTextures(vf, videoBuffer.buffer);
        }
        processNewChunk();
    } 
}

async function createVideoTextures(frame: VideoFrame, buffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    let f
    try {
        // console.log('frame', frame, buffer, typeof frame.codedHeight);
        f = frame.clone();
        await f.copyTo(buffer);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error caught:', e);
    } finally {
        // console.log('videoBuffer', buffer);

        // frame.close();
    }
    
}
```

| hardware | Browser | error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2020 2 GHz 4 core Intel Core i5 | Chrome 121 | undefined |
| MacBook air 13-inch, 2020 Intel Core i3 | Chrome 121 | undefined |
| MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2020 2 GHz 4 core Intel Core i5 | Safari | no error but very laggy |
| MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2020 2 GHz 4 core Intel Core i5 | Chrome 109 | no error |
| MacBook Pro 14-inch, 2021 M1 pro | Chrome 121 | no error |
| MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2021 M1 | Chrome 121 | no error |
| MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2021 M1 | Chrome 121 | no error |
| Ipad pro, 2021 M1 | Chrome 120 | no error but very laggy |
| Ipad pro, 2021 M1 | Safari | no error but very laggy |
| Iphone 13 | Chrome 120 | no error but very laggy |
| Iphone 13 | Safari | no error but very laggy |
| Xiaomi 11 pro, snapdragon 888 | Chrome 120 | no error |

I guess it is a problem with the chip architecture, but there is an x86 device that does not meet the requirements.

Comment: Given your data this looks to only be an issue on the x86 build of Chrome for Mac. Unfortunately, there's not a great deal we can do about this. You could try [switching to the Dev channel for updates as this is on v123](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2024/01/chrome-dev-for-desktop-update_25.html), so you would at least be able to discern if it's been fixed in a later build.